# Easiest way to get a simple sales data graph

Tags: orange

I'm a coder but have very little knowledge of data science.

I'm want to use Orange for very simple data visualizations. Starting from a sales data table with columns like "date" (datetime), "total" (number) and "class" (a string) I want to make three simple line graphs:

- one showing the total by time and
- one showing one line per class showing the total and
- one showing one line per class showing the number of sales.

I don't understand how I go about this or what kind of input the line chart even needs. The example in the docs even shows the line chart with categorical data in the x-axis, which makes for a somewhat weird example.

Obviously something will have to group the dates by a suitable time unit, such as days, but it's not obvious from the group-by node how to do this.

Does someone have an example or can give me some clues?